Forces on a 18th century ship
I am trying to make a 18th century ship simulation where the ships are moved by the aerodynamic forces in their sails and the hydrodynamic forces on their hulls. The simulation is in 2D, so I ignore all vertical forces (i.e. forces not parallel to the water surface.) I've been reading some very good articles on the subject (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forces_on_sails is particularly good,) and it seems like most forces affecting ships are described by the drag equation,
$$
F = \frac{1}{2}\rho v^2 AC_D,
$$
with $\rho$ the density of the medium (air or water), $v$ the velocity difference between the ship and the medium, $A$ the cross-sectional area of the ship, and $C_D$ the drag coefficient (as far as I understand.)
The forces are highly dependent on the angle of attack $\alpha$, i.e. the angle at which the medium hits the hull or sail. This dependency is taken care of by $C_D$, which really should be written as $C_D(\alpha)$ Forces are often split into two components. Drag, which is aligned with the angle of attack and lift which is perpendicular to it. Drag arises when the sails catch wind, or when the hull moves through water, and lift arises from pressure differences in exactly the same way as they do for an airplane wing.
This is all my understanding so far, but I still have a lot of, unanswered. questions. Hope you can help.

Is the cross-sectional area $A$ constant? Intuitively it shouldn't be, but all the articles I've read are very vague with the dependencies of the parameters. Also, in the articles I've only seen $C_D$ being graphed as a function of $\alpha$, and I know $C_D$ takes things like -the "streamlined-ness" into account, which is related to the geometry, of the, affected object. For a flat sail, it makes sense to me that $A$ is constant, and that $C_D$ might have a $\cos(\alpha)$ dependency that "shrinks" the area when seen from the side, but for a ship hull it is less clear what $A$ is used.
When the hull is moving around in the water it feels resistance to the movement, which the articles suggest again is modelled by the drag equation. The lateral resistance should of course be larger than the forward resistance, otherwise the ship would be able to sail sideways with as much effort as forwards. If I use only the drag equation, the difference in the forward and lateral forces arises through the differences in the $A$'s and/or the $C_D$'s. I can guess values for $A$ pretty easily from the dimensions of the ship, but $C_D$ is less clear. Even when I hike up the lateral $C_D$ to what feels like unnaturally high numbers (real $C_D$'s lie between 0.05 and 2.30), the ship's movement seem unnatural. It remains very easy to get unnaturally high lateral movement, which I think is due to the $v^2$ dependency. Intuitively, the ship should be very resistant to lateral motion, even when stationary. Is there another resistance force at low speeds that I am missing?
One possible low-speed force is lift-induced drag (see figure below.) The wiki article about lift-induced drag (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift-induced_drag) describes the force only in terms of wings on a plane, using for instance the parameter $b$ for wingspan. How can I apply this to a ship, and not a plane wing? Is it even relevant?

Any help, resources, clarifications, or corrections of wrongful assumptions are greatly appreciated.


Please narrow this to a single question.
